# Visual Studio 2015 can't read settings from csproj file

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Yesterday my VS2015 suddenly stopped being able to read the settings from any csproj files, and I've no idea why.  There are several symptoms of this:

- I get many warnings when opening a project, saying "Load of property
  'OutputPath' failed", "Load of property 'AssemblyName' failed" etc.
  etc.
- Most tabs on the project properties page are blank and read only
- The Resources tab on the project properties page often gives the error "Error loading type library/dll. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))"
- An error occurs if I try to open the designer for any forms ("The
  designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes
  within it can be designed....The base class
  'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could not be loaded....")
- I can build the project but the exe does not appear in the bin\Debug folder (the vshost.exe *does* appear), and if I try to debug then an error dialog pops
  up saying it couldn't find the exe and then "...Please build the
  project and retry, or set the OutputPath and AssemblyName
  properties..."

I don't know what caused this to suddenly start happening, I have been using VS2015 without issues for a long time.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS2015 but it made no difference, I've spent a long time searching the web but haven't found anybody else reporting the same symptoms. I'm hoping I don't need to re-image my machine, so any ideas would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: antivirus? project on network share or on external storage?

Comment: Try deleting the bin folder.  Removing the bin folder will force all files to recompile.  Sometimes a file in the bin folder gets locked and the compiler can't over write existing files so deleting will remove these files.  If you can't delete any of the files then rename the file (to any thing) so the compiler can create a new file with original name.  The compiler copies any reference dll libraries into the bin folder.  It looks like one of the dll is missing.  Do you have any reference dll from other projects?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I don't think it's antivirus (it's not affecting anybody else) and the project is on a local drive.
I tried removing the bin folder but it didn't make any difference.  n.b. this problem affects every project, not just 1 specific project, and many of the problems occur before I get as far as building the project